# AggregationStrategy with org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Invalid correlation key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I want to aggregate 3 topics, but just for PoC of Aggregate Strategy,  I'm trying to aggregate 2 topics.

So, I've configured the following Camel routes:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
CamelContext contexto = new DefaultCamelContext();
try{
    onException(SQLException.class, Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .maximumRedeliveries(1)
            .process(new CustomExceptionProcess());

    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("file:data/error") // There is no file created 
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliveryDelay(5000));

    from("kafka:topic1") 
            .process(new ProcessTopic1()) // inside this process 
            .to("direct:agregador");

    from("kafka:topic2") 
            .process(new ProcessTopic2())
            .to("direct:agregador");

    from("direct:agregador")
            .aggregate(header("idAgregador"), new EstrategiaAgregador()) // implements AggregationStrategy
            .completionPredicate(predicadoTamanhoMinimo()) // This just to check if is there at least 2 objects before realease the aggregation.
            .eagerCheckCompletion()
            .to("direct:insereBanco")
            ;

    from("direct:insereBanco")
            .process(new ProcessoInsere());

}catch (Exception e){
    LOG.error("Error in the route: ", e);
}
```

And the process for topic1 and topic2 is just this:

```
// It's the same process for ProcessTopic1 and ProcessTopic2
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    if(!(exchange.getIn().getBody() instanceof Object1)){

        String someData = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody();

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object objeto = parser.parse(someData);
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) objeto;

        ObjectMapper mapeadorObj = new ObjectMapper();
        Object1 someEntity = mapeadorObj.readValue(json.toString(), Object1.class);

        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
        producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:agregador", someEntity, "idAgregador", someEntity.getId());
    }
}
```

But, when I got the first message by to aggregate, the message leave (because have to wait for the second message), but soon this message exit, I got this exception:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Invalid correlation key. Exchange[ID-XXXX-1597437627634-0-1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.doProcess(AggregateProcessor.java:302)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.process(AggregateProcessor.java:271)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
>>  at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
>>  at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.doRun(KafkaConsumer.java:326)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.run(KafkaConsumer.java:215)
```

One thing is I'm also using a Kafka topic to send the messages, and since this appears in the stack trace, I'm not sure if I also need to set something to Kafka as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route you are already doing a `.to("direct:agregador")`. Why are you using a producer template to send it in the processor?

What seems to be happening is that the processor is sending `someEntity` to the aggregator successfully in the exchange, but when control is returned to the route, since you have not set the body of the exchange as `someEntity`, the exchange still holds the original message without the `idAgregador` header.

What you can do in your processor is to remove the producer template code and add:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("idAgregador", someEntity.getId());
exchange.getIn().setBody(someEntity);
```

Comment: I see your point - I will take a look into it. If this fixes my issue I will mark your answer. And thanks anyway.